# How to use Pylons / Mako templates to make an HTML email from a stand alone python script?

Tags: python, pylons, mako

I'm basically asking how to "include" the plyons and mako files in a stand alone python script?

I have a working web site, but what I want to do is use Mako templetes to format emails that I  initiate through a cron script.  I want to do it this way to reuse as much code as possible, as sometimes actions in the web site generate emails.

I could make the cron script access a certain URL, and then use pylons to generate the email, but that hack has many obvious problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with Pylons but to just render a template you can

```
from mako.template import Template

mytemplate = Template(filename='email.html')
sendemail("text@example.com", "me@example.com", mytemplate.render())
```

The "standalone" approach is basically the way Mako gets used with a lot of WSGI frameworks like CherryPy.

[Mako Docs](http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/usage.html#using-file-based-templates)

Comment: Thanks.  That works great.  Also, just a FYI to others, can pass variables into render as named variables.  That is mytemplate.render(c=my_var)  this will have my_var be visable in the template as c